# How to add a CClayer on top of another CCLayer in android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, andengine

I am building a game in which i need to add a common topLayer as a common menu to other Layers. I am using AndEngineCocos2dExtension.
 Current code :

```
 public class LobbyLayer extends CCLayer {

    CPButton low, medium, high, friends, vip;
    CCSprite low_selected, medium_selected, high_selected, friends_selected,
            vip_selected;

    CCNode tables[];


    public LobbyLayer() throws IOException {



        CCSprite background = new CCSprite("gfx/bg.jpg");
        background.setPosition(400, 240);
        attachChild(background);

        CPTopLayer topLayer = new CPTopLayer();
        topLayer.setPosition(0,240);
        attachChild(topLayer);
```

This is my second layer , I have a welcomeLayer ,which has a button for this(LobbyLayer), topLayer is the layer which i want on the top of the lobbyLayer.

But Instead I get a black Screen on the emulator, it is working fine without the topLayer.Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what branch you're on but GLES2 doesn't use layers anymore.  When I searched andengine.org/forums for Cocos2dExtension, this is what I found:

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tools/porting-to-ios-t8450.html

> I believe the cocos2d extension is so we can use cocos builder to build menu's and stuff so we have a graphical interface.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the z value for the layers. I have used while adding child layer in parent layer as :

```
addChild(background,1);//z value 0

addChild(topLayer,5);//z value 5 so appear above background layer
```